# Jquery form submit after confirn with setting submit button

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am using JQuery and SimpleModal Confirm Modal Dialog to show a confirm box before uploading. The form is submitting fine but as i'm checking isset submit button in PHP therefore it fails. How could i submit post using JQuery with setting submit button. 
Here is the code

HTML

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#duc" method="post" id="uploadform" >
    <input name="file" type="file" >
    <input name="Submit_upload" type="submit" value="Upload" id="Upload" >
</form>
```

JQuery

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  $('#Upload').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    confirm("Continue to the Upload?", function () {
        $('#uploadform').submit();
    });
  });
})
```

PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit_upload']) && $_FILES['file']['name'])
{
    // file uploading process.
}
```

I think as after confirm JQuery submitting the form so the actual submit button is not adding in the post array. any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: could just check for the `$_FILES['file']` instead? I assume you error if it's not there anyway.

Comment: i could but in a single page there is more than one form with different type of file upload so i have to check from which button it was caled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you submit the form via `.submit`, `type=submit` input values are not sent at the same time.  There are a ton of different ways to solve/handle this.  One is to do:

```
<input name="Submit_upload" type="hidden" value="true">
<input type="submit" value="Upload" id="Upload">
```

The hidden input *will* be sent.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code and it is working fine man

i just use one page to use your code. on top i put your PHP code then jquery code in head after jquery.in and then  html part and its working fine why it is not working in your machine might you clean cache or browser;
here is my code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit_upload']) && $_FILES['file']['name'])
{
   echo $_POST['Submit_upload'];die;
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script>
jQuery(function ($) {
$('#Upload').click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
confirm("Continue to the Upload?", function () {
    $('#uploadform').submit();
 });
});
})
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#duc" method="post" id="uploadform" >
    <input name="file" type="file" >
    <input name="Submit_upload" type="submit" value="Upload" id="Upload" >
</form>


</body>

</html>
```